# How to Write a extension method that I can use over string and int both?

Tags: c#, string

I have a method like this in my code that help me to generate a comma based string

```
 public static class Extensions
    {
        public static string ToCommaList(this IEnumerable<string> val)
        {
            if (val.Count() == 0)
                return string.Empty;

            string ret = "";

            foreach (var str in val)
            {
                ret = ret + str + ",";
            }

            ret = ret.EndsWith(",") ? ret.Remove(ret.Length - 1, 1) : ret;

            return ret;
        }

    }
```

Now I have a problem with my code that it won't work over list of int. What I want to do is generate comma list no matter it's string or int. I want to check if it's list of int or string in my function the process on it and generate string.

I have a tried to refactor IEnumerable but I didn't feel it's good. I only allow 2 type of object (string and int only).

Do someone can show me the code so it will allow me to pass int and string both and it will generate the comma list.

Comment: Have generic IEnumerable type -this IEnumerable<T> val where T is of type int/string

Comment: On a separate note, you would want to use a StringBuilder instead of concatenating strings.

Comment: @thumbmunkeys You can have `struct`....

Comment: Why don't you just use `string.Join()`?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead you're right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public static string ToCommaList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> val)
{
    if (!val.Any())
        return string.Empty;

    return String.Join(",", val);
}
```

Comment: or even just `return String.Join(",", val);`

Answer (score 0):

you should have a generic IEnumerable Like this one:

```
public static string ToCommaList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> val)
    {
        if (val.Count() == 0)
            return string.Empty;
        string ret = "";
        foreach (var str in val)
        {
            ret = ret + str + ",";
        }
        ret = ret.EndsWith(",") ? ret.Remove(ret.Length - 1, 1) : ret;
        return ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static string ToCommaList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> val) where T:class
        {
            if (val.Count() == 0)
                return string.Empty;
           StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
            {
                var strng = val.Select(x => x.ToString());
                foreach (var str in strng)
                {
                    sb.AppendFormat("{0},", str);
                }
                return sb.ToString().Trim(new char[] { ',' });
            }
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
            {
                foreach (var str in val)
                {
                    sb.AppendFormat("{0},", str);
                }
            }
            return sb.ToString().Trim(new char[] { ',' });
        }
```